# Access violation where there wasn't one before

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, graphviz, access-violation

I'm P/Invoking out to Graphviz [as shown here](http://implicitoperator.com/blog/2009/12/24/rendering-an-in-memory-graphviz-image-with-c.html). When I wrote that blog entry, the code worked just fine. Now, I'm putting together an `HttpModule` that renders Graphviz graphs using that code, but I get an `AccessViolationException` at `agmemread`.

```
// Native signature
Agraph_t agmemread(char *);

// P/Invoke Signature
[DllImport(LIB_GRAPH)]
private static extern IntPtr agmemread(string data);

// Usage
IntPtr g = agmemread(data);
```

Like I said, this worked perfectly before. But now, I can't get my code to work in anything. Even my old Graphviz apps based on the same code don't work anymore.

What could I have possibly changed that would cause this? I haven't even downloaded a new version of Graphviz or anything, so the DLLs are all the same.

**EDIT:** I tried changing `string` to `StringBuilder`, but that produced the same result. Then, I added a `MarshalAs` attribute:

```
static extern IntPtr agmemread([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string data);
```

With that, I no longer get an `AccessViolationException`, but Graphviz fails to read the string correctly and returns a null pointer.

Comment: same data?  OS bitness the same (32/64bit)?  Do you know if the AV is actually on that line, or somewhere inside the agmemread() call?

Comment: Same data, same OS. `agmemread` is a native function, so I have no idea what it's doing under the hood to cause the access violation.

Comment: How about MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr) instead?  I know nothing about Graphviz, but Bing tells me the parameter is a 'char *', not wchar.

Comment: `LPStr` doesn't work either. I had tried `StringBuilder` because the parameter is a `char *`, but that did nothing. `LPWStr` is the only thing that is even close to working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unmanaged code rarely needs a lot of help from C# to start generating access violations.  There's nothing wrong with your P/Invoke signature, that cannot be the cause.

The most common source of AVs in unmanaged code is heap corruption.  C/C++ code doesn't have a garbage collector, memory must be managed explicitly.  Not only must it take care of releasing memory (or it will leak), it is also responsible for allocating the correct size and making sure that the code that writes to the allocated memory doesn't write past the end of the allocated memory block or writes into memory that was already freed.  That last requirement is where C/C++ code often fails.

The trouble with heap corruption is that it is extremely hard to diagnose.  It can go unnoticed for quite a while.  The typical damage done is that the internal heap structure is compromised, or the data in another heap allocation is overwritten.  That doesn't cause a problem until later, when the heap block is released or the overwritten data is used.  The code that generates the exception is not actually responsible for the damage that was done earlier.  Which sets you off on the wrong track trying to find the source of the problem.

Finding the real trouble maker is very hard, you'd have only a few breadcrumbs to figure out what might have gone wrong.  It is very hard when you have the C/C++ source code, but running it in a debug build with a debug allocator helps.  It is impossible when you don't have the source code.

Unless you can pin-point a problem with using the API from earlier calls made, you'll need help from the vendor or support group to really solve this problem.  Good luck.

Comment: I believe you hit the nail on the head! Before the access violation exceptions, I had been supplying invalid data to `agmemread`, causing it to fail. So, with what you said in mind, I thought maybe `agmemread` wasn't cleaning up properly when it fails. I restarted my machine to get a clean slate and now it works just fine with the original code and proper input data. However, I started trying to reproduce it by making multiple invalid calls to `agmemread`, but it's not exhibiting any access violations this time. Very strange. Perhaps I'll email the Graphviz developers about it.

Comment: By the way, when I said "cause it to fail" and "make multiple invalid calls", I mean so that the function returns a null pointer, which is what it's supposed to do when an error occurs.

Comment: Sure, the code that's usually tested least is the error handling code.

Comment: I submitted a bug report to the Graphviz team and they think it has to do with how the parser tries to recover from errors. Hopefully it gets resolved soon. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, again!

Comment: I'm getting something similar with GraphViz interop AccessViolationException at `if (gvLayout(gvc, g, layout) != SUCCESS) ...`  Failure rate is 1 out of 4 maybe but always at that spot. Any updates?

Comment: gvc and g are IntPtrs which have been tested to not be 0.  layout is a string.  Now, if gvc and g need to be pinned or something like that, I can't think of what it is that I have control over.  You mentioned an error-handling bug in GraphViz.  Any idea what error it is so my DOT format can avoid it?  Thanks.